# SSIS - Tools for checking which data type mapping file is being used

Tags: types, ssis, mapping

Does anyone know if there's any tools that one can use to determine which datatype mapping file is being used in SSIS 2012.

I've tried using Process Monitor but it looks like SSIS parses through every single file found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\MappingFiles to find an appropriate file to use.

I have a new mapping file that has 3 protocols under sourcetype:
    SourceType="SQLOLEDB;SQLNCLI*;System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection"

However, only the datatypes for SQLOLEDB and SQLCLI* protocols are being mapped according to what's stated in the new mapping file. Most of datatypes for System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection are mapped correctly except for 2 datatypes which I cannot determine why.

Can anyone give some advice on any tools/techniques that I can use to troubleshoot this problem?

Note: In case anyone is wondering, I did restart SSDT / Import Export Wizard before each verification is done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you help me understand how I could simulate your problem?

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for replying. I have the following mapping in my new mapping file: 
<dtm:SourceDataType>
 <dtm:DataTypeName>varcharmax</dtm:DataTypeName>
</dtm:SourceDataType>
<dtm:DestinationDataType>
 <dtm:SimpleType>
  <dtm:DataTypeName>LONG VARCHAR</dtm:DataTypeName>
 </dtm:SimpleType>
</dtm:DestinationDataType>

<dtm:SourceDataType>
 <dtm:DataTypeName>nvarcharmax</dtm:DataTypeName>
</dtm:SourceDataType>
<dtm:DestinationDataType>
 <dtm:SimpleType>
  <dtm:DataTypeName>LONG VARCHAR</dtm:DataTypeName>
 </dtm:SimpleType>
</dtm:DestinationDataType>

Comment: @billinkc Basically the mapping maps the following from MSSQL to someDB:
   nvarcharmax to LONG VARCHAR
   varcharmax to LONG VARCHAR

I am tyring to create a package using SSIS Wizard and after selecting the source and destination I checked the mappings by clicking on the 'Edit Mapping' button. That's how I check whether the datatypes are being correctly mapped or not.

Is this info sufficient for you to simulate the problem? Thanks again!

Comment: @plasticdoor66 have you solved this ? can you share your solution if yes ?